# Constant that indicates Access or Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am writing some macros for general use. I have a macro that should be executable under Access and Excel. I have tried the following idea.

```
#If Application.Name = "Microsoft Excel" Then
    sFile = Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".")) & "foo"
#ElseIf Application.Name = "Microsoft Access" Then
    sFile = Left(CurrentDb.Name, InStrRev(CurrentDb.Name, ".")) & "foo"
#End If
```

Of course this doesn't work. The object Application doesn't exist at compile time. My question is whether is there a constant that indicates that the macro runs under Access or Excel?

Comment: I think all you have is the "Conditional Compilation Arguments" in the General tab of the VBProject Properties dialog.

Comment: You're right. I just wanted to keep it as simple as possible. Less steps as possible when I am inserting the macro.

Comment: Would just an IF...else work in the code, with access library in excel and vice versa?

Comment: @TimWilliams You can define compiler constants in modules too, but they can only be assigned literal values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *only* use Compiler constants in a Compiler condition. That means you'd have to adjust the constant values *before* deploying, like so:

```
'Requires References to BOTH Excel AND Excel
#Const AccessHost = False
#Const ExcelHost = True
#If ExcelHost Then
    sFile = Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".")) & "foo"
#ElseIf AccessHost
    sFile = Left(CurrentDb.Name, InStrRev(CurrentDb.Name, ".")) & "foo"
#End If
```

If you want something more dynamic, and you don't have early-bound references to both Excel and Access, then you don't want compiler directives, but you do need to use late-binding to make it work in both hosts:

```
Dim app As Object 'Late-binding
Set app = Application
If app.Name = "Microsoft Excel" Then
    sFile = Left(app.ThisWorkbook.FullName, InStrRev(app.ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".")) & "foo"
ElseIf app.Name = "Microsoft Access" Then
    sFile = Left(app.CurrentDb.Name, InStrRev(app.CurrentDb.Name, ".")) & "foo"
End If
```

Comment: The way with the compiler constants on the other hand, doesn't correspond to my idea (of course it works too).

The idea with the latebinding is great and works as I imagined. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I think your second method won't even compile. `Thisworkbook` can't be resolved in Access, and `CurrentDb` can't be resolved in Excel.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez The second code-block did have a syntax error (missing `Then` on the `ElseIf` statement), now fixed, but otherwise it does compile, even if you're using Word, **because** `app` is an `Object`, the calls to `app.ThisWorkbook` and `app.CurrentDb` are both *late-bound*, and each statement is only ever reached if the correct `app.Name` is a match for the current host.

Comment: Indeed. I had written something, inspired by your idea, but I had not put `app.` before `Thisworkbook` and that why it did not compile. Greta suggestion, finally :-)